# Styles not working in dynamic component's template

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I have a blog and I want to get post content from the server and paste it into a component's template.

I get post data (and also post content) in PostComponent and pass it as a template to dynamic component.

Post content can contain vue directives.

**PostComponent.vue:**

```
<template>
...
    <component :is="{template: content}"></component>
...
</template>
```

But styles not applying to content from server.

How can I make it works?

Comment: Please add to your question how you are trying to apply style.

Comment: Can you show us how you are applying styles.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by removing styles from component scoped styles and added them to `scss` file.